# General best-pair algorithm with a value function

Tags: algorithm

So suppose I have two sets of nodes L and R, and a Value function that takes two nodes (one from L, one from R) and returns the "weight" of their pairing.

Is there an algorithm that would produce optimized pairs, that is pairs of the highest possible sum of Value's? Each member of L and R can only be in one pair.

Edit: I forgot one additional rule, the nodes can be of two "types": simple and complex. If a complex is paired to another complex then they can't be in another pair, same for simple types. But a complex can be paired to multiple simples (and only simples).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark That's an absurd claim to make - this is the maximum weight bipartite matching problem, and there are definitely better algorithms than brute force.

Comment: This sounds like a matching of maximum weight on a bipartite graph. That's a flavour of the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), and can be solved quickly. You should, however, clarify what you mean by "pairs of the highest possible sum of values" - is that the sum over all assignments, or some (sub)set of maximum weight pairs?

Answer (score 0):

This is an assignment problem. [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm#The_algorithm_in_terms_of_bipartite_graphs) is one of the most efficient ones for this problem on bipartite graphs (and your graph is bipartite).